# Fill checkout fields values from URL variables in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, get, checkout

I have a URL with a lot of variables put in there using GET e.g. checkout/?FirstName=Test&LastName=Test&EmailAddress=Test

I was wondering how to prepopulate the fields on the WooCommerce checkout page using this information? i.e. get FirstName and fill out FirstName in WooCommerce Checkout?

Any help thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here below is an example with billing first name and last name based on **Get url variables** for checkout fields.

Its based on your Url example: `checkout/?FirstName=Test&LastName=Test&EmailAddress=Test`

The code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_get_value' , 'custom_checkout_get_value', 20, 2 );
function custom_checkout_get_value( $value, $imput ) {
    // Billing first name
    if(isset($_GET['FirstName']) && ! empty($_GET['FirstName']) && $imput == 'billing_first_name' )
        $value = esc_attr( $_GET['FirstName'] );

    // Billing last name
    if(isset($_GET['LastName']) && ! empty($_GET['LastName']) && $imput == 'billing_last_name' )
        $value = esc_attr( $_GET['LastName'] );

    // Billing email
    if(isset($_GET['EmailAddress']) && ! empty($_GET['EmailAddress']) && $imput == 'billing_email' )
        $value = sanitize_email( $_GET['EmailAddress'] );

    return $value;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

Comment: Thanks this works any idea on how to prefill the "jump menus" e.g. country I tried using the above but doesnt seem to work for dropdowns

Comment: @AaronFernandes My answer here was based on what you asked in your question… I will try to find the way later on for select fields if there is any. **For the country and states, I think that the values need to be the country code and the state code as defined in [Woocommerce `WC_Countries` class code**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wp-content/images/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Countries.html)… those code for countries are 2 letters and for states something similar too depending on the country.